# Set secondary DNS server as automatic

Tags: windows, dns

I have configured my DNS server for my Windows devices to be Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) and it was working well. However, when connecting to certain internets, my DNS stopped working. It's a huge hassle to switch my DNS server from a static address to automatic and back again.

Is there a way to have my primary DNS server as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) and my secondary as automatic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  I think you mean "Cloudflare", and you are using `1.1.1.1` as your primary DNS server, but I am not entirely sure.  So please edit your question, as currently written, your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, my autocorrect was messing with me. I tried to edit accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean "automatic"? Do you want your computer to change the second DNS server setting to any of an unlimited number of possible DNS servers? Do you want it to use one from a predefined list?

Answer (score 0):

You can play on the fact that at home you have another DNS server inside
the router.

You may then set your router to use Cloudflare DNS, and your home devices to
automatic DNS.

This means that at home you will be getting your DNS through the router,
and it's the router that will use Cloudflare DNS.
Your computer will use whatever DNS server it finds
available on the network you are connecting to.

Whenever your connect to a network, your computer will use DHCP in order
to get an IP address. The DHCP server also sends back the DNS server
it was configured to use or itself.
The home router will normally send back itself.
If your DNS is set to Automatic, the computer will use that DNS server
automatically, which at home is the router+Cloudflare,
while outside of the home it will use whatever it can find.